# machine stack overflow in critical region (fatal)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, puma, webrick

Trying to run-up a Rails 4 project I developed 4 years ago, and I'm maintaining since then, I've got the next error that stucks the app on start:

> machine stack overflow in critical region (fatal)

I have no problems during this 4 years, but recently, trying to add some many features that my client ask me for, I've found this and the process freeze hear. Sounds like infinite loop occurs somewhere in the code when updating gems, so... I need some help if possible...

Comment: We cannot read minds. Share some code you suspect to introduce this, otherwise, this question has zero chances to be answered.

Comment: A vague error when "starting the app"? You need to be a lot more specific than this if you hope someone might be able to answer the problem.

Comment: No problem without that. First of all I wanted to know if someone has experienced sth like that. This is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/foncho/84255e74966f88121bc3d08d8cd54f7a) you'll find gem installed via bundler with version 1.17.

Comment: No more actions than `bundle install` done.

Comment: I've got the same error. Very frustrating! Using Phusion Passenger + Rails 5.2 + Ruby 2.6.2

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using `wicked_pdf` version `1.2.x`? Some [similar reports](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/810) I've seen recently show the same error.

Comment: I was using `wicked_pdf` version `1.2.x` with no problems until today that I have experienced that issue. In any case, I'll try to downgrade the `wicked_pdf` gem, to check if is that the issue or not. Thanks in advance @TomLord

Comment: `wicked_pdf` version `1.2.0` was [released](https://rubygems.org/gems/wicked_pdf/versions/1.2.0) on March 17, 2019. So I **strongly** suspect you ran `bundle update`, not `bundle install`.

Comment: No, I ran `bundle install`, not `bundle update`. Maybe when I tried to deploy the project in my laptop on wednesday (the first time I ran the project to solve an issue of one of my clients) I executed `bundle update`, but this command had no the effect I experienced yesterday.

Comment: If I posted it here is because I was no able to find any reason that justified the behaviour I experienced yesterday. Thanks and apologize to @TomLord for the inconveniences I have caused you with my question. In any case, the last thing I imagined was that `wicked_pdf` going to cause this behaviour when rendering the login page and not when trying to build a PDF file.

Answer (score 3):

in my case, and using [Tom Lord's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1954610/tom-lord) advice about `wicked_pdf` version, downgrading that the app worked again! Many thanks!

Comment: Indeed, downgrading from v1.1 to v1.0.6 for a Rails 4.2 app did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Here was my config:
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Phusion Passenger + Apache2
- Rails 5.2.2
- Ruby 2.6.2
- Bundler 1.7.2

Installed gems:
- devise 4.6.1
- http-2.0 0.10.1
- net-scp 2.0.0
- thin 1.7.2
...

I reverted to my previous Gemfile.lock config and it now works. I suspect one of these gems is faulty.

Comment: See above -- if it's the same issue, then probably `wicked_pdf` is the cause. In future, I'd suggest posting this information in a new question, and including *all* relevant information - i.e. the entire `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`, not just 4 gems followed by "...". In fact, if "reverting the the previous `Gemfile.lock`" solved the problem, then you could even try upgrading gems one-by-one to track down the faulty one.